# Keep 9 characters intact and rename all files in a folder

Tags: bash

I am new with Bash, and trying to rename files in my folder keeping the first 9 characters intact and get rid of anything that comes after.

abc123456olda.jpg > abc123456.jpg

I wrote this;

```
for file in *
do
    echo mv "$file" `echo "$file" | sed -e 's/(.{9}).*(\.jpg)$/$1$2/' *.jpg
done
```

Did not get it to work. Can someone guide what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the `rename` command instead of writing your own script.

Comment: It says command not found, I am using Windows git bash.

Comment: Sorry, assumed you were using Linux.

Comment: You're missing the ending backtick. Is that in the real script or a copying error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off, try this:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
    echo mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed -E -e 's/(.{9}).*(\.jpg)$/\1\2/')"
done
```

There are some corrections. A important one is that `$1$2` should be `\1\2`, and you need the `-E` flag to sed so that it understands the grouping with parenthesis.

Once you see the command is alright, remove the `echo` from the second line so `mv` actually gets executed.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Now since I want the same directory where the files are to be renamed there itself, I suppose I do not need the mv command. Right? I am not wanting it to be renamed and then move somewhere, just rename and keep it in the same directory overwritten.

Comment: You do need it, although it is called `mv` it changes the names of files.

Answer (score 1):

Use bash's built-in parameter expansion operator rather than `sed`.

Also, you should put `*.jpg` in the `for` statement, not the `sed` argument; what you're doing is processing the contents of the files, not the filenames.

```
for file in *.jpg
do
    mv "$file" "${file:0:9}.jpg"
done
```

`${file:0:9}` means the substring of `$file` starting from index 0 and having 9 characters.

Comment: I know, but the original code appears to be designed for filenames that always have more than 9 characters before `.jpg`.

Comment: Ok, I thought of an (ugly) `??????????*.jpg` pattern to match files with at least 10 characters before the suffix or alternatively to strip the suffix, then extract the part and add the suffix (`x=${file%.jpg}; y=${x:0:9}.jpg`) and compare the new filename against the original one before moving.